# How to create a nested hash through dynamic forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, dynamicform

I am exploring dynamic forms for my app and currently I would like to build a nested hash and currently following [Railscasts' ep 403](http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms). Thus, the following are my model and form:

Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product_type
  serialize :properties, Hash
end
```

Form:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :product_type_id %>

<%= f.fields_for :properties, OpenStruct.new(@product.properties) do |builder| %>
  <% @product.product_type.fields.each do |field| %>
    <%= render "products/fields/#{field.field_type}", field: field, f: builder %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The output I am getting is:

```
"properties"=>{"Name"=>"Great Prod", "Remarks"=>"Super!", "Year"=>"2015"}
```

Data structure view:

```
- properties
 -- Name: "Great Prod"
 -- Remarks: "Super!"
 -- Year: "2015"
```

What I am looking for is:

```
"properties"=>{"2015"=>{"Name"=>"Great Prod", "Remarks"=>"Super!"}}
```

Data structure view:

```
- properties
 -- "2015"
   --- Name: "Great Prod"
   --- Remarks: "Super!"
```

How do I go about the above to achieve it? Thank you!

Edit 1: Corrected the expected hash for the above and added simple data structure view.

Comment: Your expected hash looks wrong to me.

Comment: Thanks @Pavan for highlighting it, I have corrected it.

Comment: Anyone is able to assist in this?

Comment: I'm trying to do this same thing. Can you help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958515/using-has-many-through-with-dynamic-forms-rails-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of using hash for year, I actually created a new model for year and from there, store each properties as hash.